# The service '/_vti_bin/client.svc' does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-designer, client-object-model

when i go to mysiteurl/_vti_bin/client.svc I am getting exception "The service '/_vti_bin/client.svc' does not exist". The same does not happen in my staging environment, it is available there.Because of this exception my ECMA client object model code and sharepoint designer is not working properly. How to resolve this issue?.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you modified anything manually in your SharePoint Roo (14/15-Hive) directory?

Comment: Thanks James for the reply. No I haven't modified anything manually in 14/15 hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client.svc is missing in the ISAPI folder. So I copied the client.svc file from another server and placed on this server. Now the exception is not coming but I have a different exception(500 error code exception).